# "Nested" anonymous functions/function handles in Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, lambda, anonymous-function

Working on my Python these days, and I want to port a short Matlab code from a course I did a few years back into Python, but to be honest I can't figure out if it's possible to do it in the same manner, and if it is, how to do it.

The essential part here that I'm struggling with in Python is the following:

```
nk = @(x)1
for l=1:3 % calculate basis
    nk = @(x)(nk(x).*(x-1));
end
```

How the code works in Matlab:

`nk = @(x)1` creates a function handle `nk(x)`, which can be called by `nk(xi)` where e.g. `xi=[1,2,3,4]`, but as of now it will only return 1 since it doesn't depend on the variable `x`, yet.

In the for-loop, `nk(x)` is multiplied with `(x-1)` for every iteration (here `x` is considered a "symbolic" variable, or what to call it, similar to how you define a lambda function), and in the end it should turn out as `nk = (x-1)*(x-1)*(x-1)`.

It is still a function which I can call as `nk(x)`, where `x` is an array with whatever values I want it to have.

Comment: Even though you have given the example by I do not understand the desired behaviour of the function. Can you be little more specific, as I like many others won't be knowing matlab

Comment: Sure. For a general overview of anonymous functions in Matlab, you can look at https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-70285 .

For the code I've pasted, the goal is to get an interpolation polynomial as a function handle so it can be evaluated on different intervals without doing all the calculation over for every set of data. Say I want to interpolate some data for which I know P(x) = 0.25*(x-3)^2+0.31*(x-7.21)^3, the code above gives me exactly this P(x) so I evaluate it as (x,P(x)) (similar to numpy.polyval). Normally I don't know this P(x) a priori.

Comment: Working on your Python... What have you tried so far? What are the issues?

Comment: Added the explanation from the function to the code. Hope that also clarifies a bit more.

Comment: I meant what python code have you done so far to solve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you want us to write it for you or are you going to work on your Python and make an attempt??  Sometimes, in Python you approach the problem differently.  http://danielhomola.com/2016/02/09/newtons-method-with-10-lines-of-python/

Comment: @chapelo I'm struggling to figureo ut the part in the second nested for-loop. E.g., is it possible to first define a lambda function nk = lambda x: 1, and then call this on itself as I can in Matlab? As you can see, I first define nk = @(x)1 (which I'd guess equals nk = lamnbda x: 1). Say all the values in xv equals 1, and k = 3, how can I make nk = (x-1)*(x-1)*(x-1), but keep it as an anonymous function so I can evaluate it by nk(xi), where xi can be whatever values I want.

Comment: In Python you can create functions which are local to an enclosing function, and you don't need lambda to do so. Do (inside of your overall function) `def N(x): ...` Furthermore, this `N` can be returned like any other Python object.

Comment: @wwii Of course not, all I'm asking for is help for defining the part I just wrote about in my previous comment.

Comment: For those of us that are not matlab savy; can you explain, in words, the process that is taking place in that portion of the code? Please include it in the question.

Comment: @wwii I edited the question now and removed everything not related to what I'm actually curious about. Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following crude example of piecewise linear interpolation might give you an idea:

```
def interpolate(xs,ys):
    #assumes that xs and ys are same-length lists
    #of real numbers, with xs sorted
    def N(x):
        if x < min(xs) or x > max(xs): return False #we don't extrapolate
        if x == max(xs): return ys[-1]
        i = 0
        while xs[i] <= x:
            i+= 1
        m = (ys[i]-ys[i-1])/(xs[i]-xs[i-1])
        return ys[i-1] + m*(x - xs[i-1])
    return N
```

For example,

```
>>> f = interpolate([0,1,2],[1,2,4])
>>> f(0)
1.0
>>> f(0.7)
1.7
>>> f(1.9)
3.8
>>> f(2)
4
>>> f(2.1)
False
```

The key concept is that of *closures*. See [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/) blog post for a nice discussion (especially the part that talks about function factories).

By the way, you can create closures with anonymous functions, though the resulting code isn't very readable:

```
>>> f = (lambda x: (lambda y: x+y))
>>> g = f(3)
>>> g(2)
5
```

Since you were mentioning function "handles", I don't think that you really want anonymous functions (especially given your original question that had more Matlab code).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. A bit clearer now, but I obviously have to dig more into inner functions. If I understand it correctly, the inner function have access to all the variables that are defined inside the "outer" function, even with the variables not being passed as arguments to the inner function explicitly? 

As for the interpolation part in the original question, it wasn't the core of my question, but I accept that I wasn't specific enough to begin with, so that's on me.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The outer function provides the context in which the inner function is defined, and that context is "remembered" even after the outer function call ends. Different invocations of the outer function will create different closures, so you can, e.g. use `interpolate` to create any number of piecewise linear functions which can be used simultaneously (by the way, my interpolation code wasn't very efficient. A better approach might be to use the module `bisect` to determine which two values of `xs` to use for `N(x)` -- rather than the linear search I used).